# OpenVINO serving - Servable not found for request

Tags: tensorflow-serving, grpc-python, openvino

I am trying to serve a OpenVINO model using procedure mentioned in [OpenVINO model server repo](https://github.com/IntelAI/OpenVINO-model-server/tree/master/example_client) but encountering the below issue when trying to get the metadata for the model.
Command I am executing is

```
python get_serving_meta.py --grpc_address 0.0.0.0 --grpc_port 9001 \  
--model_name my_model --model_version 1
```

Error I am receiving is:

```
    Getting model metadata for model: my_model  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "get_serving_meta.py", line 97, in <module>  
    result = stub.GetModelMetadata(request, 10.0) # result includes a dictionary with all model outputs


    File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 549, in __call__  
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None) 
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 466, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)  
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:  
        status = StatusCode.NOT_FOUND  
        details = "Servable not found for request:Specific(my_model, 1)"  
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1555239621.319103888","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Servable not found for request: Specific(my_model, 1)","grpc_status":5}"
```

To get the docker container up, cmd I am using is:

```
docker run --rm -d -v /home/rachit/models/:/opt/ml:ro -p 9001:9001  \
docker.io/intelaipg/openvino-model-server:latest \
/ie-serving-py/start_server.sh ie_serving model \
--model_path /opt/ml/model1 --model_name my_model --port 9001
```

The directory tree structure for /home/rachit/models is

```
models/
|-- model1/
|---|---1/
|---|---|--- frozen_inference_graph.bin
|---|---|--- frozen_inference_graph.xml
```

Docker Logs:

> 2019-04-14 10:36:03,862 - ie_serving.main - INFO - Log level set: INFO
>   2019-04-14 10:36:03,863 - ie_serving.models.model - INFO - Server start loading model: my_model
>   2019-04-14 10:36:03,865 - ie_serving.models.model - INFO - List of available versions for my_model model: []
>   2019-04-14 10:36:03,865 - ie_serving.models.model - INFO - Default version for my_model model is -1
>   2019-04-14 10:36:03,876 - ie_serving.server.start - INFO - Server listens on port 9001 and will be serving models: ['my_model']

I am a newbie so any help would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the problem description there is incorrect --grpc_address parameter.
It should be the IP address of the service exposed in the openvino model server docker container. If you are connecting from the same host, where the docker is started, just use localhost value:
`python get_serving_meta.py --grpc_address localhost --grpc_port 9001 --model_name my_model --model_version 1`

Beside that you need to mind the client proxy settings. In your case `http_proxy` should be unset or `localhost` should be included in `no_proxy` variable.